# Given a solution of an ODE, how to find a solution to A DIFFERENT ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Suppose we're given a solution of an ODE represented as an integral, how can we find a solution to a different ODE?
In particular, suppose The ODE $$x^2 \frac{dx}{dy} + xy = \sin(x)$$ with initial value $y(1)=y_0$ has a solution represented as $$y(x) = \frac{1}{x}\left[y_0 + \int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt\right] $$
Then how can we represent the solution to $$ 11x \frac{dy}{dx}=y+11x\cos(x)$$ with the initial value y(1)=0 as a definite integral?

Comment: For trig functions, use a backslash, eg ``$\sin x$``

Comment: Did you mean $x^2\frac{dy}{dx}$ in your first ODE?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you wrote down two unrelated differential equations and asked for a connection between them. Why should there be a relation between them?